# favorite icon initial state undefined

Tags: api, next.js, undefined

I have created a favorite table when the offer is created. Now I want the user to be able to click on the heart icon on the offer to select it as a favorite. My problem is that the user has to click on it twice for it to do anything. It updates correctly on the second press.It seems the icon is initially undefined. I can't set the state to false or true because the initial state could be either. Basically, I get all the favorites and store them in a state (favorite), then I filter them with find() to match the offer and store that in a state (myFavorite). Then, on handleClick, I update the myFavorite state and the make an api call to update the favorite on the database.Here's the code. I think the issue is in the handleClick function. Any ideas?
`import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import { AiOutlineHeart } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { AiTwotoneHeart } from 'react-icons/ai';

```
   function JobDetailsPage({
   title,
   location,
   contractType,
   description,
   company,
   website,
   companyDescription,
   id,
   userId,
   }) {
   const router = useRouter();
 
   const { data: session, status } = useSession();
   const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
   const [favorite, setFavorite] = useState([]);
   const [myFavorite, setMyFavorite] = useState({});
   const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
  if (myFavorite !== undefined) {
  setIsLoaded(false);
  }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
  if (session?.user.id) {
  axios
    .get(`/api/user/${session?.user.id}`)
    .then((res) => {
      setUserData(res.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
 }
 }, [session?.user.id]);

 const getFavorite = async () => {
 const res = await axios.get(`/api/favorite`);
 const data = res.data;
 setFavorite(data);
 };

 useEffect(() => {
 const matchedData = favorite.find((fav) => fav.offerId === id);
 setMyFavorite(matchedData);
 }, [favorite, id]);

 useEffect(() => {
 getFavorite();
 }, []);

 const handleClick = async () => {
 setMyFavorite((prev) => ({ ...prev, isFavorite: !prev.isFavorite }));

  const res = await axios.put(`/api/favorite/edit`, {
  id: myFavorite.id,
  offerId: id,
  userId: session?.user.id,
  isFavorite: myFavorite.isFavorite,
  });
  };

 if (isLoaded) {
 return <div>Loading...</div>;
 }
 return (
 <div
  className="w-[80vw] h-screen   border-gray-200 border-2  mx-auto border-solid 
 rounded-lg mt-3 p-2 overflow-scroll"
  key={id}
 >
  <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row justify-between">
    {session &&
      userData?.role === 'APPLICANT' &&
      myFavorite != null &&
      myFavorite != undefined &&
      myFavorite.isFavorite === true && (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>
          <AiOutlineHeart size={30} />
        </button>
      )}
    {session &&
      userData?.role === 'APPLICANT' &&
      myFavorite != null &&
      myFavorite != undefined &&
      myFavorite.isFavorite === false && (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>
          <AiTwotoneHeart size={30} />
        </button>
      )}`
```